# Strange errors in Nuget Package Manager Console about PowerShell bindings

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2013, nuget

Yesterday, I've installed the latest version of Azure SDK and Azure Powershell from Web Platform Installer. After that, I get the following messages in Package Manager Console when starting Visual Studio 2013 (Update 4).

```
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(32) : Error in type "System.Xml.XmlNode": Exception: Cannot create a code method because of the method format. The method should be public, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(44) : Error in type "System.Xml.XmlNodeList": Exception: Cannot create a code method because of the method format. The method should be public, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(87) : Error in type "System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection": Exception: Cannot create a code method because of the method format. The method should be public, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(353) : Error in type "System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry": Exception: Cannot create a code method because of the method format. The method should be public, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(360) : Error in type "System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry": Exception: Cannot create a code method because of the method format. The method should be public, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(372) : Error in type "System.IO.DirectoryInfo": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(399) : Error in type "System.IO.FileInfo": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2977) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2984) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2991) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2998) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(3005) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(3219) : Error in type "Microsoft.PowerShell.DeserializingTypeConverter": Type "Microsoft.PowerShell.DeserializingTypeConverter" should be a TypeConverter or an PSTypeConverter.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(3648) : Error in type "System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(3733) : Error in type "System.Management.Automation.FormatViewDefinition": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.
```

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro, x64, and Visual Studio 2013 Update 4. Uninstalling Azure SDK or Azure Powershell did not help. Reinstalling PowerShell did not help. Repairing Visual Studio 2013 and Update 4 install also did not fix the issue. So I am not sure if the errors are really caused by the Azure SDK/PowerShell update, maybe something else is the problem.

There are some hints at stackoverflow about adding lines for assemblyBindings to devenv.exe.config files at different locations. This also did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem in Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be fixed with VS2015-RTM and VS2013 Update 5.